# I want to use cloudflares cli4 python cli tool to add and MX record. "1004 DNS Validation Error"

Tags: linux, command-line, dns, python, cloudflare

Hi I am trying to use [cloudflares python](https://github.com/cloudflare/python-cloudflare) cli tool to speed up my dns administration.

The documentation is lacking a bit with more complete examples.

```
cli4 --post name="email.somedomain.com" type="MX"  content="exch2.email.somedomain.com" priority="20" /zones/:somedomain.com/dns_records
cli4: /zones/:somedomain.com/dns_records - 1004 DNS Validation Error
```

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as making `priority=` uppercase `PRIORITY=` in front of content.

```
cli4 --post name="email.somedomain.com" type="MX" PRIORITY="20" content="exch3.email.somedomain.com" /zones/:somedomain.com/dns_records
{
"content": "exch3.email.somedomain.com",
"created_on": "2019-07-17T12:05:03.688664Z",
"modified_on": "2019-07-17T12:05:03.688664Z",
"name": "email.somedomain.com",
"ttl": 1,
"type": "MX",
"zone_name": "somedomain.com"
 }
```

It would follow that I should probably uppercase all my parameters, or log a bug with their api / python project.